# De forma habitual vs. habitualmente

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sinónimos, adverbios

¿Es más correcto decir "de forma habitual" o "habitualmente" o ambas?

**Ejemplo:**

1. Actualmente 250 millones de personas siguen el baloncesto de forma habitual.

vs.

2. Actualmente 250 millones de personas siguen el baloncesto habitualmente.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: "No es lo mismo, pero es igual" una frase de Silvio Rodríguez en la canción "Pequeña serenata diurna", podría contestar tu pregunta...

Comment: Aparte de estas dos opciones (*de forma X* y *Xmente*), en España muchas veces puedes también usar *en plan X* :-) seguramente hay otras locuciones adverbiales genéricas en otros países.

Comment: Se parecen bastante. Una usa el adjetivo y la otra el adverbio. La primera da una carácterística, la segunda muestra cómo pasa la acción. Yo creo que pueden ser intercambiables para convenir una forma de decir, pero con significados distintos.

Comment: Yo no veo significados distintos, aunque la segunda suena bastante mal. La primera es preferible por un amplio margen.

Comment: Quizá en este caso, porque hay dos advervios formados con -mente, la segunda opción suena trastabillada. Sería como decir ¨Verdaderamente únicamente¨, en lugar de decir ¨De forma verdaderamente única¨.

Answer (score 2):

Ambas oraciones son correctas. Sintácticamente, la diferencia es que en la primera se utiliza una frase con función adverbial mientras que en la segunda se utiliza un adverbio directamente. Semánticamente son iguales.